# Toggle checkboxes checked/unchecked if click on

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, checkbox, toggle

I've got an ul with list-items in it. When a list-item is clicked the class of it changes to active. This is what I've got.

```
$("#verlanglijst ul li").on('click', function() {
   var activiteit = $(this).attr("class");
   $(this).toggleClass('active');       
});
```

The list-list items are created with an loop in wordpress. Wordpress also creates as many checkboxes as there are list-items.

```
<?php $activiteiten = new WP_Query("post_type=activiteiten&showposts=-1"); while($activiteiten->have_posts()) : $activiteiten->the_post();?>
    <input class="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> checkbox"  type="checkbox" />
<?php $count++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The thing that I don't get is the following: 
When an li-item is clicked, the class changes to active. That works. 
But what I also want is that the checkbox of an li-item is set to checked if the class of the li-item is set to active. And when the active-class is removed, the checkbox has to be unchecked.

Maybe you can help me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#verlanglijst ul li").on('click', function () {
                var that = $(this);
                that.toggleClass('active');
                if (that.hasClass('active')) {
                    that.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
                } else {
                    that.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        li {
            border:solid;
            border-width:1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="verlanglijst">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to toggle checkbox try :

```
that.find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !that.find(':checkbox').attr('checked'));
```